# webpack expose object as global

Tags: javascript, webpack

I have a coffeeScript file 'app.coffee'

```
root = exports ? this

class DefipsyApplication extends Marionette.Application
  user_is_superuser: () ->
    app_config.is_superuser

app = new DefipsyApplication

app.addRegions {
  modalRegion: '#modal-region'
}

unless root.App
  root.App = app
```

I want to expose the App function in the browser

so here is my webpack config

```
module.exports = {
    entry: {
        app: './coffee/app.coffee',
    },
    output: {
        path: './build/',
        filename: '[name].bundle.js',
        libraryTarget: "var",
        library: ["MyProject", "[name]"],
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            { test: './coffee/app.coffee', loaders: ['expose?App', 'coffee'] },
        ]
    },
};
```

SO whene I test in browser I found that webpack was exposed my object to the browser, but this object is englobed by an other Object

so to call my method I should do

```
App.App
```

I Want to expose my function without this global var
I need to access directely with

```
App
```

here is a scree to show the object structur

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In general, to expose Global Variables, Methods, and Modules in JavaScript, you can use several methods.

1. You could add it manually to the browser's window object by

   ```
   window.app = app
   ```

   or build a new object by

   ```
   window.app = { func1, func2,...}
   ```
2. The [expose-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/expose-loader) is an addon to Webpack, which adds modules to the global object. If you are using yarn for dependency management, you can install the expose-loader package via

   ```
   yarn add expose-loader --dev
   ```

   Alternatively, you can use the npm installer (Node Package Manager) via

   ```
   npm i expose-loader --save
   ```

   You can expose any function with

   ```
   require("expose-loader?package!functionName");
   ```

If you need more information, have a look [at my post here](http://www.matthiassommer.it/web/javascript/expose-global-variables-methods-and-modules-in-javascript/)